# How to extends classes in material UI createStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

```
import { createStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default (theme: Theme) => {
    const { primary } = theme.palette;

    return createStyles({
        test1: {
            fontSize: '30px',
        },
        test2: {
            '& > div': {
                color: primary.main,
                marginTop: '20px',
            },
        },
    });
};
```

Here I want to use class test1 in test2. How should I extend it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dollar sign to reference the other selector when using JSS:

```
test1: {
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: "pink",
  "& $test2": {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
},
test2: {
  width: 30,
  height: 30
}
```

### Reference

- https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.8.1#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet

[image: Codesandbox Demo]